# Vuejs & Firebase Storage problem. Uncaught TypeError: storage is not a function

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

I'm creating a small project with Vuejs & Firebase. Trying upload image to Firebase storage. I checked their Documentation and few tutorials. But stuck with this error.

Uncaught TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__firebase_init**.a.storage is not a function

```
// init.js

import firebase from 'firebase'
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'



// components/AddItem.vue   

 <input type="file" @change="uploadImage" value="Upload Image"/> 

uploadImage(e){

  var file = e.target.files[0]
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('products/'+file.name).put(file)  

}
```

Comment: Where is `db` defined?

Comment: I edited.. Now its firebase.storage().ref('products/'+file.name).put(file)
Can you please tell me where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting a `storageRef` as a `var` you will need to call `.put()` on that `storageRef`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file

Using your code...

```
uploadImage(e){

  var file = e.target.files[0]
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('products/'+file.name)
  storageRef.put(file)
}
```